# mysql_num_rows returned with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i need to pass two dates to a mysql query through ajax.
i have two date inputs.

this is the index.php that has the input

```
<div id="input">
<td><input type="date" name="date_start"></td>
<td><input type="date" name="date_end"></td>

<input type="button" class="button" value="Get Value">
</div>
<div id="count_display">
</div>
```

this is the getresult.php file that has the working query

```
$date_start=$_GET['date_start'];
$date_end=$_GET['date_end'];

$select="select * from tblreport where (date(date_added) between '$date_start' AND '$date_end');";
$res = mysql_query($select);
$rec_count = mysql_num_rows($res);

echo "There are <font color='red' size='3'>".$rec_count."</font> matching records found.";
```

i want to display the resulting echo from the getresult.php inside the `<div id="count_display">` in the index.php file through an ajax method which will display the result in real time without refreshing/reloading the page.

the result will be very similar to this example on this page: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp but all i need is the count of rows returned by the query.

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use.

Comment: where is your jquery code?

Comment: the question is after the 2nd code box

Comment: @q0re i don't know how to do it that's why i asked it. pretty please?

Comment: Please note that PHP's `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated. I recommend switching to using either the PDO or mysqli libraries as soon as possible. Also note that the HTML `<font>` tag is also deprecated and should not be used. Anything you need to use it for should be done using CSS instead.

Comment: @JohnConde well its the first website i've learned coding from. alright if you say so :)

Comment: @Spudley thanks for the information. i really don't know these things for i am still a student.. any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No worries. This is why it's good to make sure you learn from an up-to-date source. There are lots of tutorials on the internet that teach out-dated techniques, particularly for languages like PHP. Check the reputation of a site before relying on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily using jquery. Here is your code

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
$(".button").click(function() 
{   
var date_start = $("#date_start").val();
if($("#date_start").val()=='') date_start="";

var date_end = $("#date_end").val();
if($("#date_end").val()=='') date_end="";

var dataString = 'date_start='+ date_start + '&date_end=' + date_end;

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "getresult.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(msg){         
        $('#count_display').html(msg);                      
    }
    }); //END $.ajax

});
 });
 </script>
 <div id="input">
 <td><input type="date" name="date_start" id="date_start"></td>
 <td><input type="date" name="date_end" id="date_end"></td>

 <input type="button" class="button" value="Get Value">
 </div>
 <div id="count_display">
 </div>
```

Comment: in getresult.php use $date_start=$_POST['date_start'];
$date_end=$_POST['date_end'];

Comment: download a jquery file and paste it in js folder. In this code I use <script src="js/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>

Comment: or just use <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> instead of  <script src="js/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script> I test it. it works

Comment: there is a slight problem. whenever i press the Get Value button more than once. multiple message appears. i think its because of the append?

Comment: use $('#count_display').html(msg);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script language='javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
       $.get('getresult.php')
            .success(function(result) {
                var data = $.parseJSON(result);
                var div = document.getElementById("count_display");
                div.innerHTML = data.message;
       });
  });
</script>
```

Note, you need to include the current jquery api from jquery.com.

In PHP:

```
$message = "There are <font color='red' size='3'>".$rec_count."</font> matching records found.";
echo json_encode( array( "message"=>$message ) );
```

Comment: i didn't seem to understand the first code box. where should i put that? inside a <script> </script> ?

Comment: see update above.. put the javascript code into the index.php for example inside '<head></head>' Note: you have to include the current jquery api..

Comment: i've saved the latest api from the jquery website and saved it as jquery.js should i still include it in the index.php or the getresult.php?